# MySQL Get n records per group order by alias

Tags: mysql

Data:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  ID  |   GROUP   |    LAT    |     LNG    |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   1  |     A     | 37.937363 |   1.348025 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   4  |     A     | 60.879875 |   8.789927 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   5  |     B     | 41.637905 |  -0.936209 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   7  |     A     | 40.382008 |  -3.722799 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   8  |     B     | 47.023994 |   1.808898 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  10  |     A     | 13.369470 | 105.709335 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  11  |     B     | 59.290794 |  14.978157 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  13  |     A     | 16.271467 | 100.917656 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  14  |     B     | 50.878986 |   3.839009 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  16  |     B     | 52.367733 |  -1.645905 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I really have thousands of rows, this is just an example.

Whis this query I get the distance from where I am to every point ordered by group and distance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT 
    *, 
    IF(lat > 0 OR lng > 0, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(39.571370)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(2.651773)) + sin(radians(39.571370)) * sin(radians(lat)))* 1.609344), 0) AS distance
    FROM points
) AS t 
ORDER BY t.group, distance ASC
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  ID  |   GROUP   |    LAT    |     LNG    |    DISTANCE        |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   1  |     A     | 37.937363 |   1.348025 | 214.00082160996624 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   7  |     A     | 40.382008 |  -3.722799 |  550.5073098103634 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   4  |     A     | 60.879875 |   8.789927 |  2406.968707155803 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  13  |     A     | 16.271467 | 100.917656 |   9548.32105549451 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  10  |     A     | 13.369470 | 105.709335 | 10149.183567016042 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   5  |     B     | 41.637905 |  -0.936209 |  380.1650567381738 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   8  |     B     | 47.023994 |   1.808898 |  831.5334259849861 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  14  |     B     | 50.878986 |   3.839009 | 1260.8153715832098 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  16  |     B     | 52.367733 |  -1.645905 |  1460.560861854739 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  11  |     B     | 59.290794 |  14.978157 |   2358.22190793295 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  ID  |   GROUP   |    LAT    |     LNG    |    DISTANCE        |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   1  |     A     | 37.937363 |   1.348025 | 214.00082160996624 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   7  |     A     | 40.382008 |  -3.722799 |  550.5073098103634 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   5  |     B     | 41.637905 |  -0.936209 |  380.1650567381738 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|   8  |     B     | 47.023994 |   1.808898 |  831.5334259849861 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

How can I get n records of each group ordered by distance?